# ServiceStack 3.9.* to 4.*

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am trying to change ServiceStack in my service from 3.9.43 to 4.0.9.

I had to change several things in my code and mostly followed the [release notes for this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#the-big-refactor-of-v4).

There were a couple of weird things for me, like not finding anything to replace *ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints* or *AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase* but I could check those things after and was able to make my code to compile.

The problem is that when I run my code I get this exception in the very begining and it just kills the service:

***Method 'ExecuteMessage' in type 'ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.***

I get this when hitting the base:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;
//using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using ServiceStack.Web;


namespace ThisService {
    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase { //AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase {
        public AppHost(int wthreadMax)
            : base("This Service " + VcsInfo.ChangesetId, wthreadMax, typeof(ThisService).Assembly) {
        }
 ...
```

I am referencing in my project:
ServiceStack (4.0.9.0);
ServiceStack.Client;
ServiceStack.Common;
ServiceStack.Interfaces;
ServiceStack.Text

I am sure I am doing something wrong changing to version 4.* and am lost with what is trying to call the Execute Message since I think removed everything from the previous version. Any suggestion to where I should be looking to?

By the way, this a simple service: get json -> math + stuff -> return json.

I want to find out if a bug I found the version 3.9.43 still happens in version 4.0.9 (can't find anything specific about that bug but I believe one fix there is related) to see if I should actually re-factor my code for this version.

Comment: The code you have posted is the correct implementation of `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` which is the correct replacement for the `AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase` (the name has just been simplified). As for `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints` don't worry about this, this namespace was refactored out and isn't used in v4, *the hosting related stuff now lives under `ServiceStack.Host`* [See here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8705726) for a simple example of a working v4 AppHost. Not sure why you are getting that error without more code, what you have is right.

Comment: I'm getting the same error :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update in v4.10

This should now be resolved in [ServiceStack v4.10](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#wiki-nuget-packages-specify-min-versions) where now all NuGet packages specify a minimum version for all dependencies matching the current version. This will force NuGet to pull down the latest packages instead of the oldest matching ones.

---

NuGet seems to have the weird behavior that it will pull in the lowest dependencies when you install a package, so if you install the latest version of ServiceStack, e.g:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 4.0.9
```

It will pull in the lowest matching dependenices, e.g:

```
<package id="ServiceStack.Client" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Which is an unexpected surprise. Unfortunately ServiceStack assumes that it's always working with the latest dependencies with the same version it was built with.

So after installing ServiceStack you will need to update all your packages which will bring them in-line with the latest versions, which you can easily do in the **Updates** tab in the NuGet UI, or in the NuGet Package Console Manager with:

```
PM> Update-Package
```

### Manually remove any assembly redirects

Installing the previous **v4.02** of ServiceStack (now removed) created new **assembly redirects** for **ServiceStack.Interfaces** in the **Web.config** which you should also manually remove if they exist. These now shouldn't be created for new projects.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was because not all packages had updated with nuget.  So, this answer appears like the reason - just make sure in your bin folder all versions of the dlls are the latest.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as well.  Therefore I tried installing an older v4 version from Nuget and managed to make it work.

Using Scott's example I can get this to work correctly if I install 4.0.4:

```
install-package servicestack -Version 4.0.4
```

If I use version 4.0.5 then it runs but the example web page reports

```
Method not found: 'Void ServiceStack.Web.IResponse.set_Dto(System.Object)
```

If I use version 4.0.6 or above then I get the error reported by RGPT.

So, for now it may be a case of using the 4.0.4 version until someone with more knowledge than me replies with a better answer.  I've only just starting using [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net) today so I don't know much yet ;)

**Update:** I don't have high enough ServiceStack reputation to post a comment so felt best to edit my original post.  The answer below by **mythz** had the key bit of information.  Immediately update your nuget packages after installing **and** then check the web/config / app.config to see if any dependentAssembly bindingRedirects are hanging around - if so then remove them and away you go :)

Comment: You got my upvote as I was able to make it work using 4.0.4 exactly like you did (Great, I had tried another version before but didn't try all of them). Didn't mark it as the correct answer because it is still not working for 4.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem as well. I followed the upgrade path, first via the Beta channel before upgrading to the offical channel. What I soon realised was that the Beta libraries had version numbers greater than the official channel.

NuGet will check for a more up-to-date version locally first, before pulling in the libraries remotely. Of course, it will pull in ServiceStack v4.0.x from the official channel, but all the dependencies will come from the already downloaded Beta (i.e. locally).

What I did to resolve it:

1. Uninstall all ServiceStack dependencies from the Solution via NuGet
2. Deleted the Solution's Nuget '/packages' folder, and to re-import it using NuGet package restore
3. Re-added the ServiceStack references via NuGet, and checked the 'packages.config' for correct versions